# Ajax form submission mistake

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm just learning jQuery and working on ajax submit, but my form doesn't submit, it just redirects to my home page.

Do you see an error in my AJAX?

Form structure with url and id - using blade template in Laravel:

```
{{ Form::open(
    array(
      'url' => '',
      'class' =>'form-horizontal',
      'id' => 'invoiceForm',
      'method' => 'post'
    )
) }}
```

ajax call (Note: I am using the jQuery validate plugin)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#invoiceForm').validate({
    rules:{
        title: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 255,
        }
    },
    messages:{
        title: {
            required: 'Please enter a title.'
        }   
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
                    var title = $('#title').val();
                    var customerId = $('#customer').val();
                    var contractorId = $('#contractorId').val();
                    var taxRate = $('#taxRate').val();
                    var servicename = $('#taxRate').val();
                    var taxable = $('#taxable').val();
                    var qty = $('#qty').val();
                    var price = $('#price').val();
                    var subtotal = $('#subtotal').val();
                    var total = $('#gtotal').val();
                    var comments = $('#comments').val();


                        $.post(baseURL+'/contractors/invoice', 
                         {  
                                title: title,
                                customerId: customerId,
                                contractorId: contractorId,
                                taxRate: taxRate,
                                serviceName: serviceName,
                                taxable: taxable,
                                qty: qty,
                                price: price,
                                subtotal: subtotal,
                                total: total,
                                comments: comments
                            },
                            function(response){
                            if(response.status == 200) {
                                location.href=baseURL+'/contractors/dashboard';
                            }
                            else if(response.status == 400) {
                                $('#msgSection').empty().removeClass('alert-error alert-success').addClass('alert-error');

                                }
                            }, 'json');
                        return false;
                    }
                    });
```

The validation works, but I don't think the form is catching the .post action.  Firebug doesn't show any errors, just redirects to the index page.

Here is my Post Route (submitting to the same page the form is located on):

```
Route::post('/contractors/invoice', 'ContractorController@postInvoice');
```

Also, it may be of note that the form works fine with a php submit action.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the redirection is working, we may be right to assume that the Ajax call was successful (unless there is redirection elsewhere??).

Look at the Network tab in Firebug, you should be able to see the data sent during the Ajax request.

Might I also suggest looking up the response body from the Ajax call, it might give you more information about what is hapoening behind the curtain.

I hope this helps

Comment: I should have been a bit more clear: the page is redirecting to the homepage, but that is not a result of the ajax... The link to the homepage is not found anywhere on the form or call.

Comment: Try removing the Ajax call to see if the redirection still happens. If it does, it would mean that you are getting interference from another script. Sorry I can only give vague pointers but I would require more information to fully diagnose the problem. You might want to try getting help from the Laravel community. Do keep me informed of your progress ;)